# WP8 : is a WVGA app auto scaled for WXGA or 720P?

Tags: windows-phone-8, screen-resolution

I've developed and submitted a WP 8 app. it's a cocos2Dx game.
 I can test it on my device (WVGA) but the simulators (ex: WXGA) don't work on my PC.

I only checked "WVGA" in the WMAppManifest.xml as I can't test the other resolutions

so in the store, it is written : "App requires WVGA (480x800)"

question : is the app available and does it work (with a kind of auto scale) on devices with other resolutions ? (ex: WXGA)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you selected in `WMAppManifest.xml`. At the bottom of the application settings you will find *supported resolutions*. Tick all three and your app will automatically work on all supported resolutions.

WVGA and WXGA share the same aspect ratio of 15:9, but 720p is slightly taller and uses aspect ration of 16:9.

Read more on [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Tony, do you mean that the app will be scaled by the OS if I tick those 3 resolutions (just in the same way as WP7 app are scaled ?). Does it mean I'll have to upload screenshots for those resolutions ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to upload screenshots. But your app will automatically work. When I say scaled, I mean exactly that. If you are unfamiliar with that work, it means that the UI is *stretched*.

Comment: I understand this is the case for standard xaml app. But my app is built with coco2Dx and according to this post the CCEGLView will not be scaled but will stay in a corner. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/21258. correct ?

Comment: Well, you haven't mentioned in your original post that you are using coco2Dx and I am unfamiliar with it. So I can't really help you with that.